# How can I use the Debian GL screensavers or any others that support hardware acceleration?

Tags: screen

The sole purpose for my RPi is to use the DVI out functionality and I am going to rip apart a 19" LCD HD screen and build it into my own frame.

I already did this [with a very old notebook a few year ago](http://pkula.blogspot.co.uk/2009/06/vaio-notebook-frame.html), and being a huMAN, I want bigger and better now!

I tried the GL slideshows in Debian Squeeze from the RPi site, but that gives me 0.1FPS on any option. I suspect its because X is not using the OpenGL API yet.
*(as pointed out It is OpenGL:ES)*

Then, I went and installed the XBMC distro and was very nicely surprised that it can play avi movies encoded in xvid out of the box. It was a bit slow in the UI, but it's really fascinating. There is a built-in screensaver there, which is a lot faster, but there is very little to no control over the settings of the screensaver.

Is there something I can just load to use OpenGL screensavers for the RPi, in any distro and any configuration? I am not scared to go into hectic installs.

Comment: Have you tried chaning the ram/gpu configuations for X to use more ram for 3d rendering. Can not remember the exact where i read this now..

Comment: Your notebook project is awesome. I'll be interested in taking a look when you manage to do this with a Pi as well.

Comment: Jivings, I think the Android 4 port will be my salvation .. http://www.raspberrypi.org/archives/1700

Answer (score 8):

You need to use OpenGL:ES screensavers, not OpenGL ones.

OpenGL is a rendering framework. OpenGL:ES is the version for Mobile devices. Anything that uses OpenGL will run painfully slowly because the Pi doesn't support it, so anything that wants to do accelerated graphics needs to be modified to use OpenGL:ES instead.

Comment: Is that a set of different screen savers? I am not sure what you are referring to?

Comment: No, its a graphics API, like open gl but intended for embedded or smaller system (including phones)

Comment: OpenGL is a rendering framework. OpenGL:ES is the version for Mobile devices. Anything that uses OpenGL will run painfully slowly because the Pi doesn't support it, so anything that wants to do accelerated graphics needs to be modified to use OpenGL:ES instead.

Comment: Yes... I realised that. So how can I use OpenGL screensavers with the new API OpenGL:ES ; But as it stands it seems it has not been ported yet. I  would do it- but I have no experience in that... Soo.... Your answer does not really help me :( because it is unrelated to my question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer PhonicUK. As it stands, your answer isn't terribly useful - though I know it to be correct. Can you add some information as to what OpenGL(:ES) are and why you have to use one and not another?

Comment: Although the answer pointed out I need ES my original question remains un answered. So I cannot accept this one yet.